# Sveltekit SSR load() returns HTML for Firebase error page in addition to correct data when deployed to firebase hosting

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, svelte, server-side-rendering, sveltekit

I have a sveltekit app that I'm trying to deploy to firebase hosting. The app works great locally with `npm run dev` or `npm run build && npm run preview` but repeatedly hits 500 and a firebase error page when hosted.

This appears to be the result of the cloud function that firebase spins up returning an html error page from the server `load()` function in addition to the correct results.

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<', "
<!doctype "... is not valid JSON
```

This seems to only happen sometimes, but occasionally when visiting a page that has a +page.server.ts file, I'll get back some failed network calls from load()
[network call chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wyi3B.png)

The first successful network call contains the expected JSON result of the load function. The next 2 error responses are HTML for a firebase error page claiming that the application is deployed in the wrong directory (A refresh seems to properly load the page when this happens)

[returned firebase error page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZluMX.png)

Any ideas what's causing these html pages to be returned by load()? This also appears to still happen when pre-rendering my routes with a `page.server.ts`

I'm also seeing the following error log from my cloud function when it fails which seems unrelated to my any of my project files

```
 Error: Not found: /alf.php
    at resolve (file:///workspace/index.js:3591:18)
    at resolve (file:///workspace/index.js:3425:34)
```